# I want to store input value in an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have table and inside td i have a input field,i want to to store all the id values in to array using jquery.

```
<td class="center">
    <div id="divId">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/backend/img/small.gif" width='40px' height='30px'></img> 
    </div>
    <input type="hidden"  class="box" id="boxId" name="foo" value="<?php  echo $device->deviceId;?>" />
</td>
```

my javascript method is

```
<script>

function yourfunction() {                           
    var no=document.getElementById("boxId").value;              
    alert("no"+no);
}
var x=setInterval(yourfunction,600);
</script>
```

i tried using an loop but it didnt work always added up the first value.

Comment: Because `id` __must be unique__

Comment: so how to solve this

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you actually need.

Comment: Use `class` property.

Comment: if your hidden input didn't have an unique id but only a `name="foo"`, the use something like,
`$('input[name="foo"]').val();`

Comment: i tried somethhing like this but it didnt work  
 //var className = document.getElementsByClassName('box').value;
   //  var classnameCount = className.length;
   //  var IdStore = new Array();
  //   for(var j = 0; j < classnameCount; j++){
       //  IdStore.push(className[j].id);
     //}
//alert("no"+no);
   //  alert("IdStore"+IdStore);
}

Comment: Where is your array where you want to store the values? like var my_Array = []; and why do you want to loop? if you only store one value?

Comment: I want to store all the values in an array in  that column

Comment: share your full code. above code doesn't have `array` you want to store in and `loop` you are using to do so. it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do and what is your current approach.

Comment: ok thanks this workd     var arrNumber = new Array();
$('input[name=foo]').each(function(){
    arrNumber.push($(this).val());
})

alert("arrNumber"+arrNumber);\

Comment: You should try `var className = document.getElementsByClassName('box');` as `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object of the elements with given class and you need to iterate over it get individual value or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use class proprety because Id is unique,This is a jquery solution:

```
<td class="center"><div id="divId"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/backend/img/small.gif" width='40px' height='30px'></img> </div><input type="hidden"  class="box" id="boxId" name="foo" value="<?php  echo $device->deviceId;?>" /></td>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function yourfunction(){
     /*get all element having class "box"*/
     $( ".box" ).each(function() { 
       alert($(this).val()); /*alert current element value*/
     });
    }
    var x=setInterval(yourfunction,600);
});
```

With Javascript:

```
 function yourfunction(){
      var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("box");
      for (var i = 0; i <  elements.length; ++i) {
          alert(elements[i].value);
       }
 }
 var x=setInterval(yourfunction,600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the input elements to be processed are available on document ready:-

```
function extractBoxIds() {
  var idList = [];
  $('.box').each(function(index, element) {
    idList.push($(element).val());
  });
  return idList;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(extractBoxIds());
});
```

If not, run `extractBoxIds()` whenever all elements are available - after a timeout maybe.